# Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.ReturnBoolean'

Tags: vb.net, boolean, type-conversion, vb6-migration

First off, let me provide you with my code:

```
Private Sub txtLatMin_Exit(ByVal Cancel As ReturnBoolean)
    Dim i_SelStart As Long
    Dim str_Prompt As String


    'Save the cursor position.
    i_SelStart = txtLatMin.SelectionStart

    'Remove characters that we can't use.
    txtLatMin.Text = NumericPortion(txtLatMin.Text, True)

    'Enforce the maximums:
    If Val(txtLatMin.Text) + Val(txtLatSec.Text) / 60 >= 60 Then
        str_Prompt = "The maximum number of latitude minutes is 59.999."
        MsgBox(str_Prompt, vbExclamation, "Notification")
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf Val(Me.textbox_Latitude_Degrees.Text) + Val(txtLatMin.Text) / 60 + Val(txtLatSec.Text) / 3600 > 89.99 Then
        str_Prompt = "The maximum number of latitude degrees is 89.99."
        MsgBox(str_Prompt, vbExclamation, "Notification")
        Cancel = True
    End If

    'Restore the cursor position.
    txtLatMin.SelectionStart = i_SelStart
End Sub
```

It is flagging the error in this post title at **Cancel = True**

Please keep in mind that I am converting code from VB6 to VB.NET

Would there be any suggestions that someone could provide me with?

Comment: Consider throwing away and rewriting the code completely. The migration assistant is only useful for code that’s not going to change. As soon as you need to develop it further, it’s much better to start from scratch and do it properly, because the code that you migrated is invariably going to be a horrible mess. You do *not* want to maintain that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to change

```
Cancel = True
```

to

```
Cancel.Value = True
```